# ajax вывести Progress загрузки файлов

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, progress-bar

Не могу понять как показать прогресс загрузки файлов на сервер с Ajax.
вот сама форма и Javascript.

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      Email: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
      Files: <input type="file" name="files" multiple><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
<script>
    //form Submit action
    $("form#data").submit(function(event){
        //disable the default form submission
        event.preventDefault();
        //grab all form data
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.0.102:8080/upload',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function (returndata) {
                alert(returndata);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19127053/5812238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Email: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    Files: <input type="file" name="files" multiple><br>
    Progress: <span id='pBar'>0%</span><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    //form Submit action
    $("form#data").submit(function(event){
        //disable the default form submission
        event.preventDefault();
        //grab all form data
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        function setProgress(e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                var complete = e.loaded / e.total;
                $("#pBar").text(Math.floor(complete*100)+"%");
            }
        }
        $.ajax({
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", setProgress, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("progress", setProgress, false);
                return xhr;
            },
            url: 'http://192.168.0.102:8080/upload',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function (returndata) {
                alert(returndata);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Если ставлю этот параметр async: true то не отправляются файлы, выдают ошибку 404

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев, у Вас есть доступ к коду-обработчику на сервере? Попробуйте указать конкретный скрипт в URL (upload.php, например)

Comment: Сервер это rest на golang, для http использует gin

Answer (score 1):

[Демо, хотя оно и не сработает без реального сервера](https://jsfiddle.net/4naw88yk/)

Обратите внимание что данный код рабочий и протестирован, если у вас не выполняется **проверяйте конфигурацию сервера.**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://192.168.0.102:8080/upload',
    data: formData,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        /* Используем XMLHttpRequest.upload для получения события загрузки на сервер */
        XMLHttpRequest.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                $("#progress").text(Math.floor(percentComplete*100)+"%");
            }
        }, false);
    },
    success: function (returndata) {
        alert(returndata);
    }
});
```

Comment: Объявляется переменная percentComplete и нигде не используется, но при этом используется переменная complete, хотя нигде не объявляется... А вы говорите код рабочий и проверенный!

Comment: @unreal_serg Да, Вы правы, брал со своего проекта (по этому и утверждал), переименовывал для наглядности, недоглядел. Испрвил.